# Anything wrong with the type declaration?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I am reading the book "Programming in Haskell". One exercise asks me to define `map f` using an higher-order function. I choose to define `map (+1)` like the following:

```
unfold p h t x | p x       = []
               | otherwise = h x : unfold p h t (t x)

-- equivalent to `map (+1)`
mapinc = unfold (==[]) ((+1).head) tail
```

(Taken straight from the exercise question) The function `unfold p h t` produces the empty list if the predicate `p` is true of the argument value, and otherwise produces a non-empty list by applying the function `h` to this value to give the head, and the function `t` to generate another argument that is recursively processed in the same way to produce the tail of the list.

I have checked my implementation of `mapinc` and it looks fine:

```
*Main> mapinc [1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
```

However, after I add the type declaration:

```
mapinc :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
mapinc = unfold (==[]) ((+1).head) tail
```

Then reload the script in WinGHCi, it gives the following error:

```
• Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘==’
  from the context: Num a
    bound by the type signature for:
               mapinc :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> [a]
    at D:\7a.hs:4:1-29
  Possible fix:
    add (Eq a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        mapinc :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> [a]
• In the first argument of ‘unfold’, namely ‘(== [])’
  In the expression: unfold (== []) ((+ 1) . head) tail
  In an equation for ‘mapinc’:
      mapinc = unfold (== []) ((+ 1) . head) tail
  |
5 | mapinc = unfold (==[]) ((+1).head) tail   |                  ^^^^
```

**Any clue why it happens?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your signature is **too broad**. The predicate you have written is `== []`. Haskell can only check if two lists are equal, if the *elements* of the list can be checked as well. In the source code we see something like:

```
instance Eq a => Eq [a] where
    ...
```

Yes, here we will never check the equality of two items, since we check with the empty list, but the compiler of course does not know that: it simply sees that in order to check whether two lists are equal, we need to be able to check if elements are equal.

The `Num` typeclass does *not* imply that the type is also an `Eq` type. We can do two things here:

1. add the `Eq` type constraint to the signature:

   ```
   mapinc :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
   mapinc = unfold (==[]) ((+1).head) tail
   ```
2. more elegant: do not rely on the fact that we need to be able to compare elements, but use [**`null :: [a] -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) instead (a function that checks if the list is empty):

   ```
   mapinc :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
   mapinc = unfold null ((+1).head) tail
   ```